# Application not resumed and again start from Main Activity if opened from Home Or Background

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, android-manifest, android-homebutton

After Login I start My Application.When Application is at another `Activity` or `Fragment` and I press Home Button application goes to background.But suppose again If started from Home or Background it start from first Splash and Login screen.It is not resuming to `Activity` or `Fragment` from where it is put to background.
This is code for ActivityMain `manifest`

```
<application
        android:name="app.AppController"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@drawable/app_icon"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity
            android:name=".Splash"
            android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".ActivityTwo"></activity>
    </application>
```

This is code for `Splash` activity

```
public class Splash extends AppCompatActivity {
    private Handler handler;
    private Runnable r;
    RelativeLayout relativeLayout;
    ConnectivityManager connec;
    TextView isOffline;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        relativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative);
        isOffline=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.offline);
        connec = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        isInternetOn();
        handler=new Handler();
        r = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        };
    }
```

I have finish the Splash Activity after checking connection so what is the problem

```
 private void isInternetOn() {
        if (connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED ||
                connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING ||
                connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTING ||
                connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.CONNECTED)
        {
            r = new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    startActivity(new Intent(Splash.this, MainActivity.class));
                    finish();
                }
            };
            // if connected with internet take Action
        } else if (connec.getNetworkInfo(0).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED ||
                        connec.getNetworkInfo(1).getState() == android.net.NetworkInfo.State.DISCONNECTED)
        {
            isOffline.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Snackbar snackbar=Snackbar.make(relativeLayout,"No internet connection",Snackbar.LENGTH_INDEFINITE).setAction("Close", new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    finish();
                }
            });
            snackbar.show();
        }
```

How to achieve this so that application should be start from where it was put to background ?

Comment: Handle it in your Splash Activity using flags, can you show your Splash activity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
    .....
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
    if (!isTaskRoot()) {
        finish();
        return;
    }
    relativeLayout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.relative);
    //your code
```

Use this code in splash screen. It will resolve your problem

Comment: I have Login Code on Main Activity.If I apply this code for Splash Activity then what about Main Activity

Comment: after apply this code, your application will start from the point where you have gone to background but if the OS destroy it than it will start from Splash

Comment: Is there any code I need to add so that OS will not destroy the Activity.Because my sequence of Activity is Splash, Main Activity(Login), Second Activity where I am adding and replacing Fragments further.

Comment: isTaskRoot: Return whether this activity is the root of a task.  The root is the first activity in a task.

Comment: My root Activity is Second Activity ?

Comment: OS kills the application when it becomes low in memory otherwise not. I think there is no code for this. When you start the application first time, at that time Splash is the root. Try the code

Comment: So I need to add this `isTaskRoot` in Splash only ? Is it ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169720/discussion-between-ankit-and-satyam).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, for that after login finish your login activity and go to your particular home screen activity. Because if you are not finishing login activity then when app comes from the background it starts an activity which is in BackStack.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your device **Don't keep activities** option should be disable:

Go To:

Settings >> Developer options >> Don't keep activities, should be disable (If not make it disable and check your app).

Comment: The thing is, your app should work whether it's enabled or disabled.

Comment: But option says, when it enable "Destroy every activity as soon as the user leaves it" .

Comment: Yes, destroy the instance. But task stack record remains. When you go back from Recent Apps or Launcher it should recreate where you were. Try it.